# Caliburn Micro Datagrid Binding

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, datagrid, caliburn.micro

I'm using Caliburn Micro framework in a WPF application and I need to bind a collection to ItemsSource of a DatGrid.
Please consider below code:

Class

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<Subject> Subjects;
}

public class Subject
{
    public string Title{ get; set; }
}
```

View Model

```
public class PersonViewModel : Screen
{
    private Person _person;

    public Person Person
    {
        get { return _person; }
        set
        {
            _person = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => Person);
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => CanSave);
        }
    }
    ....
}
```

View

```
<UserControl x:Class="CalCompose.ViewModels.PersonView" ...ommited... >
    <Grid Margin="0">
        <TextBox x:Name="Person_Id" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="10,52,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="Person_Name" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="10,90,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Person_Subjects}" Margin="10,177,0,0"></DataGrid>     
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

**Problem 1:**
When I run the application the TextBoxes are getting right values, but the data grid haven't populated. 
Here i'm using deep property binding technique using convention "ClassName_PropertyName".

**Problem 2**
When I change the value of 'Name' property the 
NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => Person) is never called. I would like to call the guard method when the text changes in the Name field.

Can anyone suggest me a simple solution to overcome this issues?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Implement `PropertyChangedBase` on the `Person` class, then for `Name` we can write

```
private string name;
public string Name
{
    get { return name; }
    set
    {
        if (name == value)
            return;
        name = value;
        NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => Name);
    }
}
```

For the binding to the `DataGrid`, dont use the "deep binding", merely use

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Person.Subjects}" ...
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Is there any way to notify the parent object when child objects value changed? Ex: How to notify the 'Person' class when the value of 'Person.Name' changed?

Comment: Hi again, I have inherited the Person class from 'Screen' and I have added NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => Parent). on property 'Name'. But when changing the value of Name, the NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => Person) never called in ViewModel. Any reason?

Comment: I have miss led you here. Because you want to raise the property changed event of the parent object, you will have to look into adding an event handler on `Person`...

Comment: Thanks Killerc am. Can you please provide a simple example code?